# Image Loading Event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want that when my image is loading then GIF image should be displayed but when image loading is completed then GIF should disappear.
But I don't know how to do. Please tell me the step by step procedure.

```
imageWave1.IsVisible = !imageWave1.IsLoading;
stackBehindImage.IsVisible = true;
imageWave1.IsVisible = true;
stackFrontImage.IsVisible = false;
```

Second Image is displaying where GIF should be displayed first then until the second image is Loading

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackFrontImage" Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" Spacing="0" Margin="10" IsVisible="True">
                    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage HeightRequest="100"
                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                               x:Name="imageWave" 
                                               Source="outlet.gif"
                                               IsVisible="True"
                                               Margin="0"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout x:Name="stackBehindImage" HeightRequest="100" Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="10" IsVisible="False">

                    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage x:Name="imageWave1"
                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                               HeightRequest="50"
                                               Margin="0"/>
```

This is my XAML code.

I have written all these things but my both images(GIF and PNG) displaying together. please correct me what I am doing wrong here.

//This should be displayed when my imagewave1.source is Loading.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackFrontImage" Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" Spacing="0" Margin="10" IsVisible="True">
                    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage HeightRequest="100"
                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                               x:Name="imageWave" 
                                               Source="outlet.gif"
                                               IsVisible="True"    
                                               Margin="0"
                                               LoadingPlaceholder="imageWave1"
                                               Finish="ImageWave_Finish"
                                               DownloadStarted="ImageWave_DownloadStarted"/>
                </StackLayout>
```

//This Should be displayed after loading itself and then GIF should disappear.

```
                <StackLayout x:Name="stackBehindImage" HeightRequest="100" Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="10" IsVisible="False">

                    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage x:Name="imageWave1"
                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                               HeightRequest="100"
                                               Margin="0"
                                               Source="http://192.168.0.110/repos/xformsexperimental/RestApiTrain/images/mcdonalds.png"
                                               LoadingDelay="5"/>
```

```
 private void ImageWave_Finish(object sender, FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImageEvents.FinishEventArgs e)
        {
            stackBehindImage.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void ImageWave_DownloadStarted(object sender, FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImageEvents.DownloadStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            stackBehindImage.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

Here is the screenshot kindly check.

[image]

Comment: How did you load your image? Can you share the code?

Comment: you can use `FFimageloading` https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading.
In that you can use any image till your actual image gets load.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am using FFimageloading for loading GIF, I have two images one is GIF and second is PNG but when PNG is loading then GIF should be display and when PNG is loaded successfully then GIF should be disappear and PNG should be display.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am using FFimageloading to loading GIF image and i have tow images one is GIF and another is PNG but i want that when PNG is loading till then GIF should be display and when PNG is loaded successfully then GIF should be disappear and PNG should be display over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like this:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
                DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                LoadingPlaceholder = "loading.png"
                Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

In this **`LoadingPlaceholder`** is what you can show the loading image, once the **`Source`** image is loaded it will automatically disappear.

Comment: Is this for First image or for second image which will be load?

Comment: I didn't get your point, try to use this snippet get any sample image to understand the behaviour of plugin, later you can modify as per your requirement.

Comment: Actually i used this code it is working fine but the problem is it is  displaying rapidly after the GIF.
so do you know something that GIF should come first and take kinda time then Second Image should be display after loading itself.otherwise your answer is helpful but that is not exactly what i want.i am mentioning here screenshot kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is an property called `LoadingPlaceholder` you can use during the loading time of the image.
2. There are two events called `DownloadStarted` and `Finish`  Occurs before/after every image loading. You can use these two events to control the visible ability of your second image.

For example:

```
    <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage  HeightRequest="100"
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                       Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                       x:Name="imageWave" 
                                       Source="outlet.gif"
                                       IsVisible="True"
                                       Margin="0"
                                       LoadingPlaceholder="imageWave1"
                                       Finish="ImageWave_Finish"
                                       DownloadStarted="ImageWave_DownloadStarted"
                                       />
```

In code behind:

```
private void ImageWave_Finish(object sender, FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImageEvents.FinishEventArgs e)
{
    stackFrontImage.IsVisible = false;
}

private void ImageWave_DownloadStarted(object sender, FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImageEvents.DownloadStartedEventArgs e)
{
    stackFrontImage.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It is really helpful but it will helpful more if you could tell me about it's backend code that what should i use within "ImageWave_DownloadStarted" .

Comment: See what i have done and correct me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Manisha change stackFrontImage IsVisible="True"  to IsVisible="false". And see my edit in code behind.

Comment: It is throwing Exception that is:
Exception: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Comment: Try to update the UI in main thread? [xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: Well  Now It is Working but the thing is that image is not taking time to load itself and  it is loading rapidly so i am not able to see GIF(First Image).
So do you know that i can see the first image and it should stay for some time then it should display Second Image(PNG) i am using "LoadingDelay" but it is not working.

Comment: The loading time is depending on how fast you load the image from the url. If your network is poor, the time will be long, otherwise it will be fast as you seen.

Answer (score 0):

try this for loading indicator

```
<Image x:Name="img" Aspect="AspectFill"  />


<ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{x:Reference img}" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" />
```

Comment: what is IsLoading?