# Callback when image is loading in Xamarin Forms

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a Listview in Xamarin Forms. The content of every cell in list is text and one or more images. I search way to detect when all content in cell is finish loading. My idea is using a IsLoading property of Image. Source of images are urls http.

This is the code of the FlexLayout where the list of images is loaded:

```
 <FlexLayout  AlignContent="Center" AlignItems="Center" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="Center" Wrap="Wrap"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="media"   Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,10,0,10" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Media}">

        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                              <Image x:Name="img" Source ="{Binding Url}" HeightRequest="{Binding ListHeigth}" WidthRequest="{Binding ListWidth}"  Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

                    </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
 </FlexLayout>
```

I have not found a way to Binding the IsLoading property using the XAML. Being a list, I don't know how to use this property in each of the elements:

```cs
img.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == "IsLoading")
            {
                //do somink
            }
        };
```

How is the IsLoading property Binding  in the Xaml? Or is there some other callback to detect that all the content of the cell has been loaded?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have not found a way to Binding the IsLoading property using the XAML.

`IsLoading` just have `get` method, it do not have `set` method, so you cannnot add binding in the XAML directly.

[image]

So I advice you to use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) to achieve it.

If you want to detect when `image` is finish loading. You can  achieve the `Finish` event

```
  <ffimageloading:CachedImage 
            Finish="CachedImage_Finish"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Here is finish event background code.

```
  private void CachedImage_Finish(object sender, FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImageEvents.FinishEventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
```

If you use MVVM, you also use `FinishCommand`, then binding an command in the ViewModel.

If you want to display the loading image when loading, you can set the  `LoadingPlaceholder = "loading.png"`, here is similar thread.

[Image Loading Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646042/image-loading-event)